# Pagination bug on specific category archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have many category archive pages on my website, yet  on only 1 page the pagination is broken. Here's the page: https://www.roboticsbusinessreview.com/category/service/

This page uses category.php, and here's the pagination code:

```
            if ( paginate_links() )
                {
                    ?>
                    <div class="paginate-links archive-paginate-links">
                        <?php echo paginate_links(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                Nothing found!
                <?php
            }
```

Comment: **Removed link** This wans't meant for this question

Comment: @Lou: I don't see how this is helpful

Comment: Is there supposed to be more than 1 page? Because as far as I can see the pagination works fine, only when I click a link I get redirected back to the service category with a 301. Are you sure the problem really comes from your pagination?

Comment: The pagination definitely doesn't work for me, you can see page 2?

Comment: I can see the links, It points to page 2, when I click it I get redirected back to /category/service/. It doesn't work, but the problem may not come from the pagination, as the links are well formated compared to the rest of the site. Somewhere in your PHP or maybe in your htaccess, there's an instruction to redirect back to the root of the category. Find where it is, then why it goes there. BTW 301 means the document had moved permanently.

Comment: Usually this kind of problems with wordpress can be fixed pretty fast by regenerating the permalinks, if you haven't tried already.

Comment: o ok I understand what you're saying now. So there aren't any redirects that would cause this (checked in Yoast), and also I clicked "Save changes" on permalink settings, and that didn't fix it either